# How to get hidden field value from view page form and set as cookie value and retrieving in the same view page in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Thanks in advance, I have a index.ctp page where i have a form which has a hidden field with value = "2". when submitting the form the value is passed to the controller and setting a cookie as

```
$cookieVal =$this->request->data['hideCookieVal'];              
$this->cookie->write('hideNextCookieVal',$cookieVal, false, 3600);
```

and I am trying to pass in a variable to get that value in index.ctp so I used this

```
$this->set('nextCookie',$this->Cookie->read('hideNextCookieVal'));
```

In index.ctp page i am accessing this value in a variable name as `$nextCookie`.
I used this variable in a if condition to display the other section of the HTML page, if cookie is set but, it was throwing an error as

> Error: Call to a member function write() on a non-object
>   File: D:\wamp\www\invl_exams\app\Controller\UsersController.php
>   Line: 135

My code as below:

```
UsersController.php

<?php
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

class UsersController extends AppController
{
  function index()
   { 

Line 134  $cookieVal = $this->request->data['hideCookieVal'];              
Line 135  $this->cookie->write('hideNextCookieVal',$cookieVal, false, 3600);
Line 136  $this->set('nextCookie',$this->Cookie->read('hideNextCookieVal')); 

   }
 }

index.ctp page 

<form class="shopping-cart" name="cartTable" id="cartTable" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->webroot ?>users/index">

 <input type="hidden" name="hideCookieVal" value="2">

<button type="submit" class="next pull-right" id="nextId">NEXT</button>
</form>
<?php
if($nextCookie == 2) 
{

?>

<section>
  <table>
    <!-- Table content here -->
  <table>
</section>

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the `CookieComponent` in your controller, And also, it's `Cookie` with the `c` letter in uppercase

```
<?php

    App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

    class UsersController extends AppController {
        //Add this line
        public $components = array('Cookie');

        function index() {
            Line 134  $cookieVal = $this->request->data['hideCookieVal'];
            //Change cookie to Cookie              
            Line 135  $this->Cookie->write('hideNextCookieVal',$cookieVal, false, 3600);
            Line 136  $this->set('nextCookie',$this->Cookie->read('hideNextCookieVal')); 
        }

    }
```